# For every value in row c in d, return rows with maximum value of a

Tags: sql

I have 4 columns a ,b ,c, d

sample data

```
a | b | c | d |

1 | 1 | 101 | 0
2 | 1 | 101 | 0
3 | 1 | 101 | 1
4 | 1 | 102 | 0
5 | 1 | 102 | 0
1 | 2 | 101 | 0
2 | 2 | 101 | 1
```

Write a SQL command such that it should return those rows where for every value of c in b, return rows with maximum a

i.e
Expect output

```
a | b | c | d |

3 | 1 | 101 | 1
5 | 1 | 102 | 0
2 | 2 | 101 | 1
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.a = (select max(t2.a) from t t2 where t2.b = t.b and t2.c = t.c);
```

With an index on `t(b, c, a)`, this often has the best performance.

An alternative is window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by b, c order by a desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the database you are using. In PostgreSQL you can do:

```
select distinct on (b, c) a, b, c, d
from t
order by b, c, a desc
```